# Automating keystrokes and actions in Windows

Tags: windows, automation

I want to be able to either record key strokes or enter them in manually and be able to replay them.

For example:

#### Copy

1. Manually highlight the text I want to copy.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
   Manually position the cursor where I want to paste the text.
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>
5. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>
6. T

This would allow me to copy text into MS Word and set the formatting of the text.

Are there any tools for this?

Comment: KeePass has an auto type https://keepass.info/help/base/autotype.html

Answer (score 14):

[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) can be used to make hotkeys that do what you want.  It even has a recorder to ease the process of creating your script.

Here's a quick example I threw together based on what you're trying to do:

```
; The X, Y coordinates inside your target window to click for pasting
targetX = 0
targetY = 0

!^v::
{
Send, {CTRLDOWN}c{CTRLUP}{ALTDOWN}{TAB}{ALTUP}
WinWait, Microsoft Word, 
    IfWinNotActive, Microsoft Word, , WinActivate, Microsoft Word, 
    WinWaitActive, Microsoft Word, 
    MouseClick, left,  %targetX%, %targetY%
    Sleep, 100
    Send, {CTRLDOWN}v{CTRLUP}
    Send, {ALTDOWN}{SHIFTDOWN}{F10}{SHIFTUP}{ALTUP}{SHIFTDOWN}t{SHIFTUP}
}
```

This script makes Ctrl + Alt + V a hotkey that executes the above script.

Answer (score 7):

Check out [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/)

Comment: I much prefer autoit for this sort of thing. It is a simple, but extremely powerful automation tool. On the other hand, how does this solve the OPs issue? Simply posting a link does not answer a question, please describe how this meets their needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate anything with windows, it just depends on what your needs are and your skill level.

As recommended [autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) is probably the entry level of a category of tools that leads up to  full blown commercial automation tools which are primarily used for testing applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can do basic macros (recorded keystrokes & delays) with a Logitech G15 keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Macro Express](http://www.macroexpress.com/) for this sort of thing for years.

Good software, never had an issue with it - not free though.