# Software to automate process

Tags: windows, software-rec, automation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automating windows](https://superuser.com/questions/8926/automating-windows)

The task is to open IE, login to page with full of ActiveX controls, navigate to certain page, input data in some field which is changing every day and click save button. View source of that pages are not available due to tight security, so the software have to be smart enough, to be explained.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use an [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml) script to perform that work.  It might require some hackish work arounds like scanning certain regions of the control for the fields or text you're looking to interact with, but it should be quite possible to do.  It's quite versatile in what you can do with it.